# How to set up an sstp vpn connection?

Tags: vpn

the question is simple: how to set up an sstp vpn connection in ubuntu 11.04?
as of this moment I haven't been able to find a way to make an sstp vpn connection.

Comment: I've just found [sstp-client](http://sstp-client.sourceforge.net/), I haven't test yet, but it may help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give a try as described here, installing by yourself two programs, sstp-client and its network-manager support:

https://serverfault.com/questions/256180/ubuntu-connect-to-sstp-vpn

Answer (score 4):

For **Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS**:
manual install (`dpkg -i *.deb`) packages downloaded from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sstp-client/files/):

1. libsstp-client0_1.0.10-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
2. sstp-client_1.0.10-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
3. network-manager-sstp_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
4. network-manager-sstp-gnome_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

For **Ubuntu Desktop Linux 15.04 (Vivid Vervet) 64-bits**:

1. libsstp-client0_1.0.10-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
2. sstp-client_1.0.10-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
3. network-manager-sstp_0.9.10.0-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
4. network-manager-sstp-gnome_0.9.10.0-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb

For **Ubuntu Desktop Linux 15.10 (Wily Werewolf) 64-bits**:

1. libsstp-client0_1.0.10-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
2. sstp-client_1.0.10-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
3. network-manager-sstp_0.9.10.0-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
4. network-manager-sstp-gnome_0.9.10.0-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb

For **Ubuntu Desktop Linux 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) LTS 64-bits**:

1. libsstp-client0_1.0.10-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
2. sstp-client_1.0.10-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
3. network-manager-sstp_1.2.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
4. network-manager-sstp-gnome_1.2.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb

[https://launchpad.net/~eivnaes/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-sstp/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=xenial](https://launchpad.net/%7Eeivnaes/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-sstp/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=xenial)

Also: packages can be installed from [this PPA](http://ppa.launchpad.net/eivnaes/network-manager-sstp/ubuntu)

#### Sources:

How to set up an sstp vpn connection in **Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS**:

https://wiki.it-kb.ru/unix-linux/ubuntu/ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr/how-to-install-sstp-vpn-on-ubuntu-desktop-linux-14-04-lts-64-bits

How to set up an sstp vpn connection in **Ubuntu Desktop 15.04 and 15.10**:

https://wiki.it-kb.ru/unix-linux/ubuntu/ubuntu-15-04-vivid-vervet/how-to-setup-vpn-sstp-client-and-network-manager-on-ubuntu-desktop-linux-15-04-vivid-or-15-10-wily

How to set up an sstp vpn connection in **Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS**:

https://wiki.it-kb.ru/unix-linux/ubuntu/ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-lts/how-to-setup-vpn-sstp-client-and-network-manager-on-ubuntu-desktop-linux-16-04-xenial-xerus-lts

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: Naah, not my style: I will specifically say "downvoted" if I do and why... (and here I didn't)  I just left a comment for you to improve and you did.  I also cast a delete vote (which I just retracted) and just upvoted as well! Don't worry about the down votes too much: some people are negative and like down voting without leaving comments: I'm not and try to stay positive...  **;-)**

Comment: Fabby, thanks for the additional edition of my answer. Have a nice day.

Comment: sstp-client works, but I've found it to be very slow for some applications such as SVN (compared to PPTP it was orders of magnitude slower): `svn log --diff -r head:pastrev`

Comment: I tried to install it on Ubuntu 16.04 but it has problems with ppp library. Are you going to provide version for 16.04 ?

Comment: It may be a little later

Comment: Add info about 16.04 LTS with link to "how-to" screencast