# SSTP VPN Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have a problem adding a sstp vpn to the network manager. I did follow:
[How to set up an sstp vpn connection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63739/how-to-set-up-an-sstp-vpn-connection)
and
http://encryptedshadow.blogspot.dk/2016/06/remote-desktop-connection-from-ubuntu.html

But after installation even after restarting the network manager the option SSTP does not appear in the VPN menu. I did look around for some answers but I could not find anything 3rd day all ready.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 and I tried this:

nm-connection-editor

This will open GUI for network-manager and there was new button and create SSTP connection there.

[Original post](https://askubuntu.com/a/991642/300973)