# network-manager-sstp plugin not working on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: network-manager, 17.10, plugins

I'm trying to setup a SSTP VPN.

I installed from [source](https://github.com/enaess/network-manager-sstp) `sstp-client` and `network-manager-sstp` (v1.2.2) on a Ubuntu 17.10 box. Unfortunately, the "SSTP VPN" option does not show up in the network connection menu. Is this plugin compatble with 17.10?

Comment: Please try the packages provided in this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~eivnaes/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-sstp/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=artful

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the package **network-manager-sstp-gnome**. 
Here's what I did to make it work:
There's a PPA that provides precompiled packages for the necessary software. I added that with:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eivnaes/network-manager-sstp
...
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Then I installed the 3 packages like so:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sstp-client network-manager-sstp network-manager-sstp-gnome
```

I then rebooted but it should do to restart the network-manager service:

```
$ sudo service network-manager restart
```

After that you should be able to choose the SSTP option in the dialog where you can add a new connection. You can open that dialog with the command

```
$ nm-connection-editor
```

And then click the button that reads "Add".

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 and I tried this:

`nm-connection-editor`

This will open GUI for network-manager and there was new button and create SSTP connection there.

Comment: That opens up the menu where I expect the option "SSTP VPN" to be visible, but I still only see PPTP... Anyway, I could work around this issue by using the host's VPN connection, so don't spend too much time on it. Thanks anyway!