# I can't find the sstp VPN packages with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt, vpn

When I run the command

```
apt-cache search network-manager | grep sstp
```

It comes up blank. I can find pptp and openvpn, but not sstp.

Have the relevant sstp packages been removed?

[edit] - This worked for me

I ran the commands below

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eivnaes/network-manager-sstp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install network-manager-sstp
sudo apt-get install sstp-client
```

I then opened network connections with

```
nm-connection-editor
```

and I was able to set up a VPN from there.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/63739/how-to-set-up-an-sstp-vpn-connection

Comment: Thanks, I found a working solution by exploring some links there.

Answer (score 6):

The following worked on 16.04 LTS: I ran the commands below

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eivnaes/network-manager-sstp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install network-manager-sstp
sudo apt-get install sstp-client
```

I then opened network connections with

```
nm-connection-editor
```

and I was able to set up a VPN from there.

Answer (score 2):

On ***MY*** sydtem (YMMV) I did `locate sstp`, and found `/usr/share/nmap/scripts/sstp-discover.nse`, which says in part,

```
Check if the Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol is supported. This is
accomplished by trying to establish the HTTPS layer which is used to
carry SSTP traffic as described in:
    - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc247364.aspx

Current SSTP server implementations:
    - Microsoft Windows (Server 2008/Server 2012)
    - MikroTik RouterOS
    - SEIL (http://www.seil.jp)
]]

--SSTP specification:
--    _ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc247338.aspx
--
--Info about the default URI (ServerUri):
--    - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947054
--
--SSTP Remote Access Step-by-Step Guide: Deployment:
--    - http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc731352(v=ws.10).aspx
--
--SSTP enabled hosts (for testing purposes):
--    - http://billing.purevpn.com/sstp-manual-setup-hostname-list.php

author = "Niklaus Schiess <nschiess@adversec.com>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, this is a soulution (this enables gui interface):

```
sudo apt install network-manager-sstp-gnome
```

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS: "Unable to locate package network-manager-sstp-gnome"